# Trying to compare and print only members with Inactive status

Tags: java

1. Trying to compare and print only members with Inactive status. The problem is that it will not search the array and check the status of each element. If the first element has an "Active" status, it prints the error message and doesnt continue to check the other elements.
2. If the status of the first element is "Inactive" it will print but throws an exception before the output which looks like this:

   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException   at
       GymAss.MemberTest.AllInactive(MemberTest.java:293)  at
       GymAss.MemberTest.main(MemberTest.java:58)
3. Account Number: 1  Name: 1  Date: 1  Status: INACTIVE  Type: 1  Any
       help would be greatly appreciated! Code below:

....

```
 public static void AllInactive()

    {
    int check=0;
    do  

        {
        if ( accounts[check] instanceof Student && accounts[check].getStatus().equals("INACTIVE") )                
        {


            System.out.printf("\nAccount Number: %d \nName: %s  \nDate: %d \nStatus: %s \nType: %s \n" , accounts[check].getIdNumber(),accounts[check].getName(),accounts[check].getDateJoined(),accounts[check].getStatus(),accounts[check].getMemberType());
            check++;

        }
        else if ( accounts[check] instanceof Adult && accounts[check].getStatus().equals("INACTIVE"))
            {


                System.out.printf("\nAccount Number: %d \nName: %s \nDate: %s \nStatus: %s \nType: %s \n" , accounts[check].getIdNumber(),accounts[check].getName(),accounts[check].getDateJoined(),accounts[check].getStatus(),accounts[check].getMemberType());
                System.out.print("\n");
                check++;


            }
        else
        {
        System.out.println("**Account Does Not Exist**");
        }

        } while ( accounts[check].getStatus().equals("INACTIVE"));

}
```

Comment: which line is 293? You shuld step with a debugger and check which variable in this line is `null`.

Comment: Why do you do the same condition twice?

Comment: I use the same condition twice because I originally had while ( accounts[check] != null ); and it would infinite loop the error statement which was annoying me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to make sure we are talking about the same thing: As far as I understood you have an Array containing accounts of persons. What you want to do is get all the accounts which currently are inactive and nothing else.

Why do you stop your loop if you find an active account? If you have an inactive account followed by an active followed by an inactive again, your loop will stop at the active one, because the condition of `while(accounts[check].getStatus().equals("INACTIVE"))` is false. You want to check the whole array so you have to loop through the whole array. This can be done with

`for(int check=0; check<accounts.length; check++)`

This checks every account and stops if you reach the end of the array. There is even an easier way. I recommend looking up "java foreach".

The cause of your `NullPointerException` propably is not checking if you reached the end of your array. Let's assume you have only one inactive `Student` account in your array and nothing else, your code will do this:

- `check = 0;`
- is `accounts[0]` a `Student` and is it inactive? - yes

  - print stuff
  - `check = 1`
- skip `else if`
- skip `else`
- is `accounts[1]` active? wait, there's no `accounts[1]` -> `NullPointerException`

I don't want to give you the complete code because trial and error is a great way of learning so try to fix it with those hints. If you encounter any problems you still can't solve after a while of thinking, come back.

Comment: thanks for your help. I got it working perfect in the end. I used the for each as well which I found much easier and basically all I had to do was increment check in the else statement when I wanted to move to the next element instead of printing a message which was retarded of me. Thanks again for the help!